# Entering binary numbers using input()

Tags: python

```
binnum = bin(input()) 
print (int(binnum))
```

Works but I have to enter my binary number with a preceding `0b`, anyone know?
I would also like to know if someone knows how to insert a loop so it asks until you press something or even so I can have a denary to binary in the same program

Comment: Are you certain you are running this in Python 3? This code doesn't work **at all** in Python 3, but if you entered `0b01` in Python 2 the first line would work, the second still would not.

Comment: You also need to come up with better question titles; how do you expect people to come look at this question?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a string containing a binary number:

```
s = input()
```

If you want to interpret it as a binary number:

```
int(s, 2)
```

And if you want to print it in binary:

```
bin(int(s, 2))
```

For example:

```
>>> s = input()
010111
>>> a = int(s, 2)
(a equals 23)
>>> bin(a)
'0b10111'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is being forced to be binary.  Your output is being created as int (base 10).

I think you want to have:

```
num = int(input())

print (bin(num))
```

since there's nothing that makes a number *inherently* binary.  It's just a number.